# Bottom corners arent round

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm having an issue with some container views.
The main view has 2-container views. One of them is just a container view, straight up from the drop-off menu with nothing more than it's child VC being modified via Storyboard. (the embedded one).

The second Container View has a Scroll-view inside and a second view inside the container view with a custom size. (I saw a tutorial on youtube).

Now on my viewdidload on the HomeVC I call the following code:

```
func setupViews() {
    containerTop.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    containerTop.clipToBounds = true

    containerBot.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    containerBot.clipToBounds = true
}
```

The above code results in [THIS RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj8ko.jpg). As you can see all but 2 corners are rounded (the bottom 2 corners of the top view). Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried _containerTop.maskToBounds = true_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didnt work.
I was able to fix it by doing the following:
On the storyboard tree On the ViewController there is a View on the element tree. I linked that as an outlet in my code and made it's corners round. Basically I called the round corners twice:
- Home View controller had:

```
func setupViews() {
  containerTop.layer.cornerRadius = 15
  containerTop.clipToBounds = true

  containerBot.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
  containerBot.layer.cornerRadius = 15
  containerBot.clipToBounds = true
}
```

And then the ContainerTopViewController had inside a View (per storyboard) and the code is:

```
class ContainerTopViewController: UIViewController {
<LINKED THROUGH STORYBOARD> myView: UIViewController
func loadView() {
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
myView.layer.clipToBounds = true
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about why you are having this odd behaviour, I also experienced something similar and fixed like following: (Your project should be supporting iOS11++ in order for this solution to work:

```
func setupViews() {
  containerTop.layer.cornerRadius = 15
  containerTop.clipToBounds = true

  containerBot.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
  containerBot.layer.cornerRadius = 15
  containerBot.clipToBounds = true
}
```